# Update status bar text

Tags: c#, winforms

this is simplest possible thing, but i cant update text on status bar... I just started working in c# but cannot find solution..
in all answers, accepted answer is `statusBar1.Text = "text";`
I made simple menu and added LOAD item in menu. Picture is loaded, all works fine, just status text doesn't update...
Btw, MessageBox also displays right text that i need in status bar.
Here is my code, and it just doesn't work:

```
 private void menuLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Load Photo";
        dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)"
        + "|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                statusBar1.Text = "Loading " + dlg.FileName;
                pbxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());
                statusBar1.Text = "Loaded " + dlg.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show("Text = " + dlg.FileName); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusBar1.Text = "Unable to load file " + dlg.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to load file: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        dlg.Dispose();
    }
```

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: By doesn't work, do you mean the status bar doesn't update at all? Or that you don't see the "Loading" message but do see the "Loaded" message? The later is expected because you are holding up the UI thread.

Comment: Im sorry if i missed that.. Text just remains "Ready" and doesnt update. I put "Ready" text in properties of statusbar1

Comment: @Mlad3n What do you see after you closed the MessageBox.

Comment: You're not somehow resetting the text to "Ready" on each page load, are you? Your change to "Loaded ..." could be picked up, but reset back to "Ready" each time.

Comment: @I4V -  no change... Status bar still have "Ready text"... Btw, in message box, file name (and path) is displayed..

Comment: @colinsmith - i tried both refresh() and invalidate()... nothing :(

Comment: @ Jon La Marr - i guess :) i don't know really what is happening... but if i write statusBar1.Text... why should it reset on "Ready" ?

Comment: Hold on a minute... are you using `Windows.Forms` or `WPF`? Your tag says `WPF` but your use of `DialogResult` suggests `Windows.Forms`.

Comment: Windows.forms.. Missclicked there... Sorry... I removed that tag

Comment: done :) i addeded the right tag :)

Comment: Please post the sections of your Designer.cs where the status strip is added. How did you add the status bar exactly? http://www.visualcplusdotnet.com/visualcplusdotnet22f.html

Comment: @Mlad3n I added the picture you linked to in a comment (you can't post pictures at 40 rep can you?); feel free to edit your post to add a bit of context around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the text gets set but just doesn't get painted because your thread is busy loading a picture? You can try to force the status bar to invalidate and repaint itself:

```
statusBar1.Text = "Loading " + dlg.FileName;
statusBar1.Invalidate();
statusBar1.Refresh();    

pbxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());

statusBar1.Text = "Loaded " + dlg.FileName;
statusBar1.Invalidate();
statusBar1.Refresh();    

MessageBox.Show("Text = " + dlg.FileName);
```

Actually I think I'd encapsulate this into a method, like this:

```
private void UpdateStatusBarText(string text)
{
    statusBar1.Text = text;
    statusBar1.Invalidate();
    statusBar1.Refresh();    
}
```

This way your `try` block would look like this:

```
UpdateStatusBarText("Loading " + dlg.FileName);

pbxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());

UpdateStatusBarText("Loaded " + dlg.FileName);
MessageBox.Show("Text = " + dlg.FileName);
```

**EDIT**

The `StatusStrip` control is a container control. Add a `ToolStripStatusLabel` item to it, and change the text of that control instead of that of `statusBar1`:

```
private void UpdateStatusBarText(string text)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = text;
    statusBar1.Invalidate();
    statusBar1.Refresh();    
}
```

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/vguuz5lvr/

Here... I did like You said and nothing is changed... "Ready is not updated..."

Comment: btw, if i do  statusBar1.BackColor = Color.Red; then background color of bar is changed... All works fine, just that text update don't want to change :)

Comment: @Mlad3n please see edit. I think you need to set the `Text` property on a `ToolStripStatusLabel`, not on `statusBar1` directly.

Comment: Yes, retailcoder :) that was mistake :) I removed text from statusBar1 and put text update on toolStripLabel :) Thanks all for help... Now it works and this is what should be done:

`try
                {

                    toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = "Loading " + dlg.FileName;
                    pbxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());
                    toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = "Loaded " + dlg.FileName;
                    toolStripStatusLabel3.Invalidate();
                }`

Comment: One more thing if anyone else have this problem... Take care about size of form.. If You don't see updated text on Your status bar, try to resize Your form :)

Answer (score 3):

> This answer relates to WPF because this question was originally tagged as `WPF`.

As @MattBurland mentioned, UI updates do not happen at the same time as execution. This means that setting different values for a UI property is pointless, because only the last one will actually be updated. Instead, you need to schedule a message on the UI thread using the `Dispatcher`. Try something like this:

```
private void UpdateStatus(string message)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
    {
        statusBar1.Text = message;
   }));
}
```

And then in your method:

```
try
{
    UpdateStatus("Loading " + dlg.FileName);
    pbxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());
    UpdateStatus("Loaded " + dlg.FileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Text = " + dlg.FileName); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    UpdateStatus("Unable to load file " + dlg.FileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to load file: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: "Loading..." status probably will not be visible unless picture i want to load is large...
I expect only to see "Loaded..." message on status bar and that is what i want.
I can't put your UpdateStatus method in my menuLoad_Click method. i get many errors... Shouldn't there be only one line of code that just change text of status bar ?

Comment: How can you put any method into another method? What do you mean? Add the `UpdateStatus` method, then *call* that method from your click handler. What errors do you get?

Comment: i get Error "The name 'Dispatcher' does not exist in the current context"...
`using System.Windows.Threading;` also is not accepted...

Comment: I've updated my code example to use the `Application.Current.Dispatcher` instead... try that.

Comment: Still the same... Never mind... I will just skip this part... I worked in Java and there is simply needed ".SetText()"... I don't understand why so much work just to change text on component...

Comment: +1 for the effort and time taken for showing the WPF way... and leaving it as an answer with the mention "relates to WPF".