# cannot update status bar text in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, statusbar

In my windows forms application I am trying to update the text on my status bar but unable to do so .
here is my code :

```
public void CreateMyStatusBar(string msg = "Ready")
 {
            StatusBar statusBar1 = new StatusBar();

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                statusBar1.Text = msg;
                statusBar1.Update();
            }));


            statusBar1.Invalidate();

            statusBar1.Refresh();

            statusBar1.Update();

            Form1.gui.Controls.Add(statusBar1);

}
```

Form1 is my main form and gui is defined as `public static Form1 gui;` in Form1.cs.

Whenever I call

> CreateMyStatusBar("ABC")

function it shows the text sent to it on the first call. but when this function is called again the text doesn't get updated.

I went through various posts like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fea2c99a-9cf0-4226-8756-2d1ef5934bcc/c-statuslabel-text-wont-update?forum=winforms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469495/update-status-bar-text) and came to write the above code but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or what i must do to resolve this?

Comment: Do you think `Form1.gui.Controls.Add(statusBar1);` **updates** the status bar? Or **Adds** a new status bar?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe  you need all the Invoke / Update functions. I've create a Form with a panel.

```
private void CreateMyStatusBar(string msg = "Ready")
{
   panel1.Controls.Add(new StatusBar{ Text = msg });
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CreateMyStatusBar("Test");
   CreateMyStatusBar();
}
```

If you don't want to create a new status bar each time, but update the existing one you could use this method. Assuming the panel should only have one StatusBar instance.

```
private void CreateOrUpdate(string msg = "Ready")
{
    var statusBar = panel1.Controls.OfType<StatusBar>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (statusBar == null)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Add(new StatusBar { Text = msg });
    }
    else
    {
        statusBar.Text = msg;
    }
}
```

If you want to create and update multiple status bars you would have to track them.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours. Then i tried calling it like Form1.gui.CreateMyStatusBar("One"); Form1.gui.CreateMyStatusBar("Two"); It always shows "One" doesn't update

Comment: CreateMyStatusBar creates a new item. If you want to update the text you need to access the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make a new statusBar each time you update the text

```
StatusBar statusBar1 = null;
public void CreateMyStatusBar(string msg = "Ready")
{
     if(statusBar1 == null) {
        statusBar1 = new StatusBar();
        Form1.gui.Controls.Add(statusBar1);
     }
     this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
     {
            statusBar1.Text = msg;
            statusBar1.Update();
     }));


     statusBar1.Invalidate();

     statusBar1.Refresh();
     statusBar1.Update();

}
```

Edit:
Does it help to use this.Controls.Add instead?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    StatusBar statusBar1 = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
    }





    public void CreateMyStatusBar(string msg = "Ready")
    {
        if (statusBar1 == null)
        {
            statusBar1 = new StatusBar();
            this.Controls.Add(statusBar1);
        }
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                statusBar1.Text = msg;
                statusBar1.Update();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar1.Text = msg;
        }


        statusBar1.Invalidate();

        statusBar1.Refresh();
        statusBar1.Update();

    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateMyStatusBar("one");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);//Wait - and blocks UI :(
        CreateMyStatusBar("two");
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours. Then i tried calling it like  Form1.gui.CreateMyStatusBar("One"); Form1.gui.CreateMyStatusBar("Two");
It always shows "One" doesn't update .